# Is node JS supported for react IOS/android apps?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I would like to know if nodeJS is compatible with react IOS/Android apps. To further explain, would there be any issues if nodeJS was the backend for my react mobile app, I know  that they are perfect to use for the web, but since react has its own backend system, would I need to ditch node js completely, or can I still make a mobile app that works with nodeJS.

Comment: Do you mean using NodeJS to run a web-server? Why not just use Electron/PhoneGap/Cordova? What advantages or features do you think you'll get from running `express.js` within Node in a mobile-device process that you can't get from PhoneGap/Cordova? Don't forget that on mobile devices your process will be tightly sandboxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to create a mobile app or a website with React that works and it is responsive for mobile browsers?

If you want to create a mobile app, you need [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) instead of React.

React Native lets you create Android and iOS apps for the front end. You can use NodeJS for your RESTful API for example as the backend.

If that is the case, you can check this article - [LINK](https://medium.com/coderinred/creating-a-react-native-app-with-node-js-backend-part-1-8fe79ac0f893) - which the guy explains what you need to use NodeJS for your React Native application

If you want a website built with React you can follow this article - [LINK](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/10/build-a-basic-crud-app-with-node-and-react) - which the guy creates a simple CRUD app with NodeJS and React

Comment: Okay thanks a LOT, I will definitely check those links.

Comment: Awesome! If that works for you I would love if you could mark my answer as the answer. Good luck @Tidris!